# Rails app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk returning 422 with "Can't verify csrf token"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nginx, ruby-on-rails-5, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Rails 5.1.4 app using Puma & nginx that's been running in production on Elastic Beanstalk (AWS) for a while. I recently opened a new QA environment in the same place and keep getting 422 errors for POST requests on the HTML calls (API calls work fine) with the message "Can't verify csrf token". Every configuration value is the same or equivalent.

I added the necessary tags and checked the authenticity token values. Under the `<head>` tag I have:

```
<meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token">
<meta name="csrf-token" content="acYjbDMNDXsw+mHN7pM/4XldHungS9kDlkkTT1moNQaf1y7wRhLJhOVb7GTMDieLU4kGc7yWlOch4DlG/z/A8g==">
```

On my login form I have the following:

```
<input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="acYjbDMNDXsw+mHN7pM/4XldHungS9kDlkkTT1moNQaf1y7wRhLJhOVb7GTMDieLU4kGc7yWlOch4DlG/z/A8g==">
```

And on the logs I receive the parameters:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"acYjbDMNDXsw+mHN7pM/4XldHungS9kDlkkTT1moNQaf1y7wRhLJhOVb7GTMDieLU4kGc7yWlOch4DlG/z/A8g==", "user"=>{"email"=>"someemail@mail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"1"}}
```

I also have the `rack-cors` gem and the following config:

```
    config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :options]
      end
    end
```

I've been trying to solve this issue for a couple days now and I'm quite lost on how to go on, any ideas on what may be causing this? Any other information that might be useful to figure out the problem?

Comment: is't api or internal call ?

Comment: internal call, updated the info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in case it helps someone in the future, I managed to fix the issue, although not completely. In my nginx config I have this line:

```
server_name *.myappdomain.com;
```

myappdomain was my production domain. I was trying to log in using my elasticbeanstalk url which was something like `http://myapp-stage.region.elasticbeanstalk.com`. I added an entry to my DNS on route 53 to alias `stage.myappdomain.com` to the elastic beanstalk URL and it worked. I suspect playing a bit more with the nginx config would solve this in a nicer way as well.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that there is some HTML caching involved, as the  tokens differ.  I've seen similar behaviour when running Varnish against a Rails backend, do you have sonmething like Rack::Cache or Nginx's proxy cache?

Comment: The interesting thing is also that you are observing this bug in QA, and it's working in production.

Comment: that is interesting indeed. I'm sorry, I pasted the wrong key on the OP, the tokens actually do match, which makes the issue hard to figure out for me :(

Comment: Time to guess again, if in the controller you're receiving the right CSRF token displayed in the HTML and there is no caching involved, then Rails is not able to find the token in the session storage --which is where it checks the CSRF token is right.  If this theory is right, then you wouldn't be able to login as session cookies wouldn't be persisted.  You could try and disable CSRF checks altogether --not in production! -- and check if you can login.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason this can happen: If nginx connects to the rails server using plain http, by default nginx won't allow rails access to cookies if they're marked secure (which they should be). There are various ways to configure NGINX to pass them through - a good summary can be found on [the unix & linux stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/307479/170153)

(Note that this likely isn't the only scenario this can happen, so check the configuration on each layer of the stack if possible)